# Force openssl cms app to not wrap content in `OCTET_STRING`

Tags: openssl, asn.1

I want to create CMS signature my custom datatype, lets assume it is named `foo.msg` and looks as follows:

```
16 01 61
```

so `IA5String("a")`

I was trying to do it with `openssl cms` tool:

```sh
openssl cms \
  -sign \
  -signer cert.pem \
  -inkey key.pem \
  -in foo.msg \
  -nodetach \
  -outform der \
  -out foo.sig \
  -econtent_type 2.999.1
```

Although this treats input as raw binary and wraps it in `OCTET_STRING`

```
a0 05 04 03 16 01 61
```

- `a0` -- EXPLICIT tag [0]
- `04` -- OCTET STRING
- `16` -- IA5String

According to [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) content may be anything:

```
ContentInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  contentType ContentType,
  content [0] EXPLICIT ANY DEFINED BY contentType
}
```

**Is there a way to force `openssl cms` to not wrap content in `OCTET_STRING`?**

*I'm not able to identify place in code where it happens.*

Comment: Generic ContentInfo.content is ANY DEFINED BY, but in CMS SignedData _EncapsulatedContentInfo.econtent_ is required (always) OCTET STRING -- see 5.2 and especially 5.2.1.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 looks like I messed up, EncapsulatedContentInfo is what I had to read about. ContentInfo seems to be top level CMS definition, not the payload.

Comment: This is fairly depressing to happen across this post after looking for a solution.
It's not *always* required to be an OCTET STRING. As a matter of fact, in Section 5.2.1 which you reference, it has an explicit exception in order to handle things like Authenticode.

Even if the standard didn't allow it, it clearly poses some practical issues. It's silly to make things difficult when there aren't even security implications here.